# Query with multiple INNER JOINS, difficulties in avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an `ACCESS BD` with a main table ('Principale') having a many-to-many connection with another ('TabRegisti'), with a join table between them ('TabRegisti_Unione').
I've a form for 'Principale' where there's a Search Button that, after the user click, creates a query for a listbox in another form.
The query that I'm using is the following:

```
SELECT Principale.ID, Principale.CodiceDVD, Principale.Cofanetto, 
       Principale.TitoloDVD, TabRegisti.NomeRegista, TabRegisti.CognomeRegista,
       TabCategoria.Categoria, Principale.Durata, Principale.AttoriPrincipali,
       Principale.Produzione, Principale.AnnoDVD, Principale.AnnoFilm, 
       Principale.DataACQ, Principale.Ubicazione 
FROM TabRegisti 
INNER JOIN (TabCategoria 
            INNER JOIN ((Principale INNER JOIN TabUbicazione 
                         ON Principale.Ubicazione = TabUbicazione.Ubicazione) 
                         INNER JOIN TabRegisti_unione 
                         ON Principale.ID = TabRegisti_unione.IDrifPrincipale) 
            ON TabCategoria.CategorieID = Principale.CategorieID) 
ON TabRegisti.IDRegista = TabRegisti_unione.IDregistaUnione 
WHERE (((TabRegisti.NomeRegista) Like "*anc*") 
AND ((TabRegisti.CognomeRegista) Like "*")) 
ORDER BY Principale.CodiceDVD;
```

I'm using the query, with the correct syntax, in VBA (the Where clause showed is just an example, of course). 
It works fine but leaves duplicates of the main table's records. 
I've tried to insert the clause DISTINCT and, after, the clause DISTINCTROW, but nothing chanced (duplicates are still there).
Otherwise, the use of the clause GROUP BY (i.e. 'GROUP BY Principale.CodiceDVD' before the clause ORDER BY) gives an error. Suggstions?

Hope the explanation of the problem is clear enough (I'm not english motherlanguage, so be indulgents).

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` will show only rows with distinct values in your selection fields. Your selected fields row must not be actually identical. You need to remove from the `SELECT` fields the once that you probably don't need and that generate a row that you don't want to see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that the query is related to a search form, so in theory every field in the select could have a request in the WHERE clause.